# does "ratchet" play nicely with "angular.js" yet?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm asking whether one page JavaScript library [angular.js](http://angularjs.org) still has/or ever had any type of 'compatability' fits with the new(ish) bootstrap-like css clone [ratchet](https://github.com/maker/ratchet/) - because before I start learning ratchet (oh and/or angular) thought I should ask..

current top result (from jan 2013) is a Google thread thus,

> I am trying out AngularJS and I have written a small app that I want
>   to use on my Android phone (galaxy s2 android version 4.0.4). I am
>   also using ratchet for the UI. The app works fine on my desktop
>   browser but it doesn't work on my Android phone. You can access the
>   app at:
>
> ....Any help would be much appreciated.

And:

> I've got this working by commenting out the  line that includes the
>   ratchet.js file. So it looks like angularjs and ratchet don't play
>   well  together.

But maybe that's either not usual situation or it's fixed anyway or something?

I guess might be bug tracker or something in angular.js land I guess but maybe someone could put the answer here for others

Comment: hmm no results for 'ratchet' in their issue tracker which is here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/search?q=ratchet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. I'm actually really impressed by it.

Comment: Great to see your blog. thanks for that. I have been struggling in my spare time with similar issues but no blog ;-) curious whether, having made the switch to ratchet you also ditched the jquery-mobile stuff or whether you are trying to use both ?

Comment: From the demo on your site i guess I just see angular stuff and ratchet stuff. Once again thanks for your comment and for your info in public like that.

Comment: We only use Ratchet. AngularJS and jQuery Mobile don't work well together. There is too much overlap, and jQuery Mobile is based on the definition of custom attributes, which AngularJS does not support very well (no conditional custom attributes). Also, with the latest release of AngularJS which supports touch and animations, there is no need for jQuery Mobile anymore. We might have to build a few controls here and there, but Ratchet is an excellent starting point. It's a match made in heaven...

Comment: I have found that using any ratchet js functions like modal don't work because when html5 mode is enabled with angular, it ignores hash URLs(which ratchet's modal depends on)... how do you deal with that?

Comment: Ideally you'd want to rewrite the Ratchet JS in more "angular"-ish fashion. I actually have this on my Todo list, as well as integrating the animations with the new animation class based system in Angular 1.2

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi Would be nice if you fix the link or you add the information that were supposed to be linked, in the answer

Comment: @Freefri Sorry, the linked blog was deleted. I removed the link to it. But the bottomline is that at the time, Ratchet worked well with Angular.js. That being said, today, I would rather use [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No. Ratchet push routing conflicts with angular routeProvider

(not only with angular, example - https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/682)

Answer (score 0):

`Push.js` in ratchet is conflict with AngularJS routeProvider which cause routeProvider not works.

Rather than include the whole bundled ratchet javascript, just use ratchet javascript components which you need. All javascript components can be found in `js/` folder of the ratchet repository.