# TWBS Ratchet - How to close modal manually?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ratchet, ratchet-bootstrap

I'm building a mobile web app with Ratchet. What I have to do is open a modal, fill a form, press a button then save and close the modal.

I'm able to close a modal with it's documented button, and I'm also able to save the form field...but how to do those things together?  In Ratchet's documentation it's not explained how to close a modal manually using JavaScript.

I'm using Ratchet with AngularJS, so the button calls an Angular function in which I should close the modal.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, finally I solved this way.
In my modal I've added this button

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="add();" href="#myModal">Save</button>
```

By pressing this button I wanted to close the modal after some logic.
So, this is my logic:

```
$scope.add = function() {
  // My logic here
  jQuery('#myModal').removeClass('active');
};
```

I hope this can help someone else...